# Where to place sys.exit() for termination of code

Tags: python

It's a beginner python program where we are given a menu and user gets to choose which item from 1-5 and 6 to exit. If they choose 6, it would terminate the code, don't ask any other questions and do not show the bill.

I thought placing it at the "elif choice == 6" would work but then it ends the whole code without considering the other previous choices

```
def get_inputs():
'''get input of each of the burger choices of the user and how much did they want'''
    count = 0
    quantity1 =quantity2=quantity3=quantity4=quantity5 = 0
    flag = True
    while flag:

        check_choice = True
        while check_choice:
            try:
                choices=int(input("Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): ").strip())
                if choices <=0:
                    print("Enter a positive integer!")
                else:
                    check_choice = False
            except:
                print("Enter valid numeric value")

        check_quantity = True
        while check_quantity and choices != 6:
            try:
                quantity = int(input("Enter quantity of burgers wanted: "))
                if quantity <=0:
                    print("Enter a positive integer!")
                else:
                    count +=1
                    check_quantity = False
            except:
                print("Enter valid numeric value")
        if choices == 1:
            quantity1 = quantity
        elif choices == 2:
            quantity2 = quantity
        elif choices == 3:
            quantity3 = quantity
        elif choices == 4:
            quantity4 = quantity
        elif choices == 5:
            quantity5 = quantity
        elif choices == 6:
            flag = False

    check_staff = True
    while check_staff and count !=0:
        try:
            tax = int(input("Are you a student? (1 for yea/0 for no)"))
            check_staff = False
        except:
            print("Enter 1 or 0 only")

    return quantity1,quantity2,quantity3,quantity4,quantity5,tax

def compute_bill(quantity1,quantity2,quantity3,quantity4,quantity5,tax):
'''calculate the total amount of the burgers and the total price of the purchase'''
    total_amount = tax_amount = subtotal = 0.0
    student_tax = 0
    subtotal = (quantity1 * DA_PRICE) + (quantity2 * BC_PRICE) + (quantity3 * MS_PRICE) + (quantity4 * WB_PRICE) + (quantity5 * DCB_PRICE)

    if(tax == 0):
        tax = float(STAFF_TAX)
        tax_amount = subtotal *(tax/100)
        total_amount = subtotal + tax_amount
    elif(tax == 1):
        total_amount = subtotal+student_tax

    return tax_amount, total_amount, subtotal
```

Expected: when starting the program and pressing 6, it will terminated without asking any other questions and also without showing the bill

Expected: code would get user's input and then when pressing 6, it will continue on to comput_bill function and compute/print the bill

Actual results: when pressing 6 at the beginning, in get_inputs, in the return statement, the local variable "tax" is referenced before assignment

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Do you like to terminate the program instantly on the press on 6 or not?

Comment: Hille, his `exit` means "to just finish taking inputs". Just write a function that will do all your processing (if possible) and call `sys.exit`.

Comment: @Hille its like if i press 6 at the beginning, it would terminate the program, otherwise it would continue asking the user for their input. When until they press 6, then it would quit the loop and continue onto the next function where it will calculate the price. hopefully i worded it right

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the loop and when you get a 6 you exit the loop. If there has been no inputs, then skip the student check and the bill calculation.

This is much cleaner than trying to use flag variables to check whether you should print.

Using `sys.exit`. Is quite a brutal way to terminate your program. It's usually best to delegate the decision to terminate to the outermost functions in your application. It's also better to let the program terminate naturally by reaching the end of the program.

You might use `sys.exit` for things like incorrect command line arguments.

```
# example prices.
unitprices = {
    1: 7.89,    # DA_PRICE
    2: 11.00,   # BC_PRICE
    3: 9.50,
    4: 15.85,
    5: 21.00
}

STAFF_TAX = 0.2


def calcbill(units, istaxable, unitprices=unitprices, taxrate=STAFF_TAX):

    subtotal = 0

    for u in units:
        subtotal += unitprices[u]

    if istaxable:
        tax_amount = subtotal * (taxrate / 100)
    else:
        tax_amount = 0

    return (subtotal + tax_amount, tax_amount)


entries = []

print("Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): ")

while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("what is the next burger? "))

        if choice == 6:
            break
        elif 0 < choice < 6:
            entries.append(choice)
        else:
            print('invalid choice')
    except:
        print('not a number')

if entries:

    while True:

        s = input('Are you a student? ').lower()

        if s in ('y', 'yes', 'true'):
            isstudent = True
            break
        elif s in ('n', 'no', 'false'):
            isstudent = False
            break
        else:
            print('not a valid value')

    total, tax = calcbill(entries, not isstudent)

    print(f'the bill was ${total:.2f} which includes ${tax:.2f} tax')
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood from the expected output, you want to exit the code in the following scenarios:-

(1) At the beginning of the code, when there is no value in the kind of the burger, just exit the code, without prompting the user to input again.

(2) After saving some values in the burger count, if the user pressed 6, then also it should not ask the user for the price calculation logic.

If my understanding is right, then you should update your code in the following manner:-

```
    if choices == 1:
        quantity1 = quantity
    elif choices == 2:
        quantity2 = quantity
    elif choices == 3:
        quantity3 = quantity
    elif choices == 4:
        quantity4 = quantity
    elif choices == 5:
        quantity5 = quantity
    elif choices == 6:
        check_choices = False
        flag = False
        import sys
        sys.exit()
```

And the output is as follows:-

```
(.test) [nikhilesh@pgadmin]$ python3 1.py 
Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): 1
Enter quantity of burgers wanted: 2
Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): 6
(.test) [nikhilesh@pgadmin]$ python3 1.py 
Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): 6
(.test) [nikhilesh@pgadmin]$ python3 1.py 
Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): 1
Enter quantity of burgers wanted: 4
Enter kind of burger you want(1-5 or 6 to exit): 6
(.test) [nikhilesh@pgadmin]$
```

Comment: is there a way where if they do save some values in the burger count and the user do press 6, it would still do the price calculation? That's what my teacher wants us to do, but I'm not sure where to put the sys.exit()